# How to give hyperlink in HTML 5 Chart in iReport

Tags: charts, jasper-reports, highcharts, ireport

I want to give hyperlink in HTML 5 Chart, so that If I click anywhere in the chart area , that should be redirected to the different report.

How can I achieve this in *iReport*?

Answer (score 2):

A Jaspersoft employee just directed me to this [article on the wiki](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/how-do-i-set-chart-hyperlinks-html5-charts). Summary of the article:

- Edit Chart Properties->Chart Data->Data Axes
- Under Categories, click to add/modify the one you want
- Click the properties tab, and then "Add"
- Give a name, such as "myUrl" and then enter the URL and close it
- Under measure, select the one you want to link and click Hyperlink
- Double click each to edit as you wish

If you want a different report depending on the slice, you'll need to set the URL expression in a property for the category bucket. The bucket properties weren't showing up for me, but I figured out you can type it in as bucket_name.property_name (say bucket was named urlBucket and property was myUrl: urlBucket.myUrl). If it is one report for the entire report, you can set it as a constant in the measure hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

Usually if you right click in any charts in Ireport and select "hyperlink" .

There you can add the hyperlink details like which report you want to add and pass parameters from main report to child report.
  You can refer [this link](http://passionfordata.blogspot.in/2012/06/how-to-add-hyperlinks-in-jasper-server.html)

(But i am not sure about HTML5 charts because I use community edition and in community edition we don't have HTML5 charts)

Comment: Hi, I know about Jfree charts. But I want to do in Highcharts specifically.